# Google OAuth2 API Redirect URI for Rails development iPad testing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mobile, oauth-2.0, localhost

I'm building an app with Ruby on Rails and a Google Apps Login. I have the login functioning  correctly on my local development machine. To test the app with my iPad, I am simply visiting the IP of the host(development) computer at port 3000. However, for the Google API Client Redirect URI, I use..

`https://localhost:3000/callbacks/outh2`

This will not work on the iPad connected to a network IP for obvious reasons. I cannot use..

`https://my.net.ip.addr:3000/callbacks/outh2`

either because Google does not accept that as valid redirect URI for the api client. So I am wondering.. Is there a better way to get this local development process to function?.. or do I need to deploy the app to a production environment just to see it on an iPad?

Thank you all for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried local tunnel? This essentially hosts your localhost address under a randomly generated temporary web address.

$ gem install localtunnel 
$ localtunnel 3000

Produces something like:
http://xyz.localtunnel.com

http://progrium.com/localtunnel/